# Promise resolve/reject evaluating instantly even though it should be waiting for another promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using a series of promises to maintain the correct order of operations so that I can load some data, and initialise some objects before my app/page loads.

In the process of making my code more modular so I can reuse some of the functions, I've seemingly overstepped my understanding of promises and I'm finding that the **.then** chain after **initApp()** is not executing ever - the promise is simply resolved/rejected instantly.

My getData function works perfectly:

```
function getData(promises, callback) {
  let getDataComplete = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(function () {
        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
          debug_log("getData: running callback");
          callback();
        }
        return resolve;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return reject;
      });
  });
  return getDataComplete;
}
```

But the section below (which executes it) doesn't wait for it to finish?

```
const initApp = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let dataReturned = getData([
    getPartners,
    getProducts,
    getCurrencies,
    getSites
  ]);
  if (dataReturned == resolve) {
    debug_log("resolve initapp")
    resolve;
  } else {
    debug_log("reject initapp")
    reject;
  }
});

initApp
  .then(() => {
    initJSComponents();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    debug_log("Problem during js component initialisation.", error);
  })
  .then(() => {
    initDOM();
  })
  .then(function () {
    //some more stuff here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    debug_log("Problem during initialisation.", error);
  });
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped and I've been looking at and rewriting it over and over for hours.

Comment: `initApp` doesn't **call** `resolve` or `reject`.

Comment: What is `if (dataReturned == resolve)` supposed to accomplish? You're comparing a function (`resolve`) with a `Promise` (`dataReturned`).

Comment: Thank you @Andreas - sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `getData` function returning `Promise`, but you didn't used `Promise#then` or `Promise#catch` methods after execution. So after the calling this function you getting `Promise` object immediately without waiting. You should probably change your `initApp` function like that:

```js
const initApp = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  getData([
    getPartners,
    getProducts,
    getCurrencies,
    getSites
  ]).then(() => {
    debug_log("resolve initapp")
    resolve();
  }).catch(() => {
    debug_log("reject initapp")
    reject();
  });
});
```

Only after that your `initApp` will resolve (or reject) his `Promise` after the `Promise` returned by `getData` function will get resolved (or rejected).

Comment: Thank you! I feel so daft in retrospect. Fixed.

Comment: Usually, if you use good IDE, you can see what type of data you getting from function. I prefer you to check if your IDE is able to detect and highlight types.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(promises, callback) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(function () {
        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
          debug_log("getData: running callback");
          callback();
        }
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        reject();
      });
  });
}
```

---

```
const initApp = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  getData([
    getPartners,
    getProducts,
    getCurrencies,
    getSites
  ]).then(allFine => {
      resolve();
  }, somethingWrong => {
      reject();
  });
});

initApp
  .then(() => {
    initJSComponents();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    debug_log("Problem during js component initialisation.", error);
  })
  .then(() => {
    initDOM();
  })
  .then(function () {
    //some more stuff here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    debug_log("Problem during initialisation.", error);
  });
```